# [Flutter]: Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method saveImageToGallery on channel image_gallery_saver)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, plugins

### Problem

I was trying to stock a widget image to the phone gallery, so I implemented `image_gallery_saver` plugin. Unfortunately, when I call this method, I kept receiving error below:

```
Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method saveImageToGallery on channel image_gallery_saver)#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      ImageGallerySaver.saveImage (package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart:20:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      InitiatePaymentState.saveImagetoGallery (package:scambio/initiate_payment.dart:611:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      InitiatePaymentState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:scambio/initiate_payment.dart:297:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

My code:

- where the plug-in is called:

```
Future<String> saveImagetoGallery(Uint8List image) async{
    await [Permission.storage].request();
    final name = 'StasticQRcode_$getVendorShopName()_$_amount';
    final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(image, quality: 100, name: name);
    return result['filePath'];
  }
```

- pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  http :
  intl:
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.3
  pin_code_fields: ^7.3.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^4.2.1
  iban: ^1.0.1
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
  path: ^1.6.4
  webview_flutter : ^2.3.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0 #qrcode generation
  qrcode: ^1.0.4 #qrcode scanning
  url_launcher: ^6.0.12 #launching url
  uuid: ^3.0.5
  encrypt: ^5.0.1
  simple_rsa: ^0.0.5
  crypto: ^3.0.1
  crypto_keys: ^0.3.0
  pointycastle: ^3.3.4
  # capture screenshot
  screenshot: ^1.2.3
  #image save
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.7.1
  permission_handler:
```

- info.plist

```
<dict>
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app needs to use Photos</string>
<...>
```

- AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:label="scambio"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

---

### Solutions used

I tried all solutions below, and none of them worked.

- Re-install the app.
- add shrinkResources false and also minifyEnabled false in build gradle.
- flutter clean and then pod install.

PS. I upgraded flutter recently, it seems all the plug-ins implemented after the upgrade won't work. Could that be the reason why the plug-in doesn't work?

All suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Is permission granted?

Answer (score 2):

You commented permission request. I think you are not granting permission.

I have checked the plugin. I think you should revisit the site.
https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver

iOS

Your project need create with swift. Add the following keys to your Info.plist file, located in

```
NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription
```

describe why your app needs permission for the photo library. This is called Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description in the visual editor

Android

You need to ask for storage permission to save an image to the gallery. You can handle the storage permission using flutter_permission_handler. In Android version 10, Open the manifest file and add this line to your application tag

<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" .....>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It doesn't work even if I added those parameters to get permissions. I upgraded my flutter recently, and it seems that all the plug-in I implemented after that won't work and shows that error. Do you think it's related to the flutter upgrade.

Comment: Are you used flutter upgrade command or downloaded the new version? Did you used flutter clean?

Comment: I used `flutter upgrade` command, and i did flutter clean, then pod install etc..

Comment: Is example project working https://github.com/hui-z/image_gallery_saver/tree/master/example ?

Comment: No, since I need to use saveImage plug-in, it provides the same problem.
`Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method saveImageToGallery on channel image_gallery_saver)`

Comment: Very good. Getting closer. :) I think the error occurs due to simulator not supporting the implementation. I faced this issue via firebase fcm token on simulator. Can you try it on real iOS device, Android device or Android emulator?

Comment: Unfortunately, i was using my iphone to run the app :/

Comment: Are you able to run a new flutter project? What does flutter doctor say?

Comment: Yes, I just created a demo project and it runs perfectly. And my flutter doctor shows no issues. Really weird, it seems to me that those plug-ins I added after the upgrade are not implemented properly.